# NodeJS. Асинхронный цикл (for await) и Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

Если я хочу запустить операции парралельно. Оборачиваю 5 запросов в сеть в промисы.

Дальше запускаю:

1)Через Promise.all

2)Через for await.

Логика исполнения будет одинакова, или нет, То-есть получу ли я парралельное выполнение?

P.S Я понимаю, что нода однопоточна и эта "парралельность" зависит от кода промиса, в данном случае (с запросами по сети) - сработает.

P.P.S какие варианты многопоточности на наде (знаю только кластер)?

Comment: 1) одновременно 2) последовательно; варианты: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: 2) awaitить нужно уже запущенные промисы

Comment: @vp_arth оно-то да, но топиктартер, кмк, намеренно разграничил all и for

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53798589

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/45285129